# Accessing svn repository from KDevelop

Tags: svn, protocols, kdevelop

I have successfully installed Subversion and set up repository for my project. Then added project to repository, checked it out and opened it in KDevelop.

I can see Subversion menu items but every time I'm trying to operate with svn within KDevelop (either add, commit or update) I've got the same error message: 
Could not start process Unable to create io-slave: klauncher said: Unknown protocol 'svn+http'.

Listing /usr/share/services shows me http.protocol but none of svn / svn+http presents.
Is there a way I can follow to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but have you tried running "kbuildsycoca4 --noincremental"? Also is this kdevelop 4?
Also more obviously, have you installed subversion?

Comment: Sorry, I was not accurate. I use KDevelop 3 and, yes, I did install subversion as I pointed it in my first sentence.

Comment: KDevelop 3 is unsupported, if you care. Looks like Rudi probably answered your question however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in KDE3 you need the `kdesvn-kio-plugins` package.